# greenhills compiler turn off optimization for file or part of

Tags: c, compiler-optimization, greenhills

I found several code snippets for disabling GCC optimization for dedicated code parts.

with pragma GCC optimize(0)

But I could not found something like that for Greenhils compiler.

Is there no such option?

Comment: Have you asked GHS support?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the manual:

```
#pragma ghs Ostring
Turns on optimizations. The optional string may contain any or all of the following letters:
L — Loop optimizations
M — Memory optimizations
S — Small (but Slow) optimizations

#pragma ghs ZO
Disables all optimizations, starting from the next function.
```

Comment: Does anybody know if this Pragma also works for static inline functions in Header-Files???

The manual does not say anything about it...